# Control Event Handling by Authohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing an AutoHotkey script in which I need to handle control events. To be more specific, I have an Edit and a buddy UpDown control. I need to respond/handle the event when user press Enter within the Edit or as another example need to respond to the changes caused by up/down control (doesn't matter user goes for arrow keys to up/down the Edit value or clicks those small up/down buttons).

Please give me a clue on how to handle control events especially about Edit and UpDown controls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joe; is there a link or something in order to accept an answer in Stackoverflow?

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/wGeFC36.png)

Comment: @DavidDe there is a checkmark-shaped icon on left side of each answer, right below traingle upvote and downvote buttons. You can upvote any valuable answers, but accept only one selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Edit` **control documentation :**
http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Edit

`UpDown` **control documentation :**
http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#UpDown

`OnMessage()` **function documentation :**
http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm

**Example Implementation :**

```
Gui, Add, Edit, gEventHandler vMyEditControl
Gui, Add, UpDown, vMyUpDown Range1-10, 5
Gui, Show
OnMessage(WM_KEYUP:=0x101,"WM_KEYUP") ; WM_KEYUP msg, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms646281
return

GuiClose: ; exit app on 'guiclose' event
ExitApp

EventHandler: ; This label is launched when the contents of the edit has changed
    GuiControlGet,value,,MyEditControl
    MsgBox MyEditControl contains "%value%".
return

WM_KEYUP(wParam, lParam) { ; this function is launched on 'Key Up' event
    if (wParam==0x0D) ; vk codes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd375731
        MsgBox Enter was pressed in MyEditControl.
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

OR,
if you have multiple Edit controls on the window and you want to handle the Enter press for particular Edit controls then improve by this :

```
WM_KEYUP(wParam, lParam) 
{ 
    ; vk codes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd375731
    IF (wParam==0x0D) ; 'Key Up' event for 'Enter'  
    {
        GuiControlGet, FocusCtrl, FocusV
        IF (FocusCtrl="MyEditControl") ; Focus is on MyEditControl Edit control
        {
            ; when Enter is pressed and when MyEditControl has the keyboard focus
            MsgBox Enter Presses on MyEditControl   
        }
    }    
}
```

Especial thanks to Joe DF for his helpful answer and nice documentation.

Comment: nice fork there, well looks my awswer helped you just fine! ;)